# Can I call Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction([transaction]) as a "one-liner"?

Tags: android, realm

I've been using Realm in an app I'm currently developing, and have found myself typing out this sort of pattern again and again:

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    realm.executeTransaction(tRealm -> {
        // Execute some transaction in here
    });
}
```

While it's not exactly ugly, and I like the fact that the try-with-resources closes `realm` for me, I have found myself wondering if it would be sufficient to simplify that to something like this:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(tRealm -> {
    // Execute some transaction in here
}
```

I would prefer this both because it's one less level of nesting, and because I'm then not getting an instance of Realm just for the purpose of calling `executeTransaction()`, which then gives me a *different* instance of Realm to use.

But I haven't switched to the second snippet because I'm concerned that the `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` part of it is going to cause me problems (since I'm not calling `close()` for it). Am I correct in my thinking, and thus should continue using the first snippet, or would I be fine to use the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second snippet is problematic in the sense that Realm keeps a references counted cache which is used to determine when the underlying resources should be fully closed, so using it means that you keep the underlying resources open, which can cause OOM errors. It is also problematic when deleting the Realm or trying to migrate it.

The above pattern is also dangerous if done on a background thread as you then keep a Realm open at an old version which can cause your filesize to increase as Realm has to keep track of multiple versions: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#large-realm-file-size

It is technically safe if done on the main thread, but since you don't release resources when going in the background the app has a much higher chance of getting killed by the system.

Comment: Ahh see, I figured the ref-counting would be an issue, but I didn't even think about the other things you listed. I'll definitely stick to the first pattern then, thanks for the prompt and detailed answer!